# How to saving log javascript to database

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

## saving log data

I've any problem with logging data.
i want to save this log into database, can u show how to saving log into database? i using morgan for getting log on API

Comment: Please, show some of your relevant code, that you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, morgan is not designed to be used that way. But there are always hacks to do it, so beware of the overheads that it might bring into your application. [This](https://github.com/expressjs/morgan/pull/44#issuecomment-62309400) link might help you in streaming the logs to the database.